# Ubuntu on old platform

Tags: boot

I have an old PC that I did a complete wipe drive on and would like to install Ubuntu 12.10 on it once the DVD order arrives.  The PC is an HP Pavillion a1610n with an old 2005 vintage AMD processor.  I do not intend this PC to be "dual boot" so what is the proper installation procedure to use?

Note:  I am not familiar with Linux/Unix

Comment: How much RAM does this PC have?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the DVD, and click 'Install Now.' Ubuntu will detect that you have no OS on it, so you won't have to dual-boot. Then follow the steps and enjoy Linux!

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 - just go ahead, install and enjoy. We do run 12.10 am64 with no issues on an *"old"* AMD Athlon X2 @2.2 GHz with 2MB RAM and a likewise old GForce 6. All is nicely supported out of the box. We are even able to run a VM on this machine.

Comment: @HaroldSpangler If it worked then why don't you accept the answer if it worked?

Answer (score 1):

You can just insert the DVD and boot to it. Once you are in Ubuntu you have the option to try it or install  it. If you want to, click install and it will walk you through the steps. It has an option to use the full drive, so select that and you will only have a single boot.

However since your pc is an older model you may want to look into a more resource efficient version of ubuntu. You can find a linux distro that is dubbed light ubuntu at: http://lubuntu.net/ .